# RavenDB - Index sorting for Alphanumeric property

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, ravendb

I am trying to index an alphanumeric property that should be sorted as follows:

```
WS1-1-14-1
WS1-1-15-1
WS1-1-15-2
WS1-1-15-3
```

I created an index that removes the non numeric characters of the property and set the SortOptions to Int so i can order then as above.

Here is my index definition:

```
        Map = fixtures => from f in fixtures
                select new
                       {
                           FixtureNumber = f.FixtureNumber.Replace("-", "").Replace("WS", ""),
                       };

        Sort(x => x.FixtureNumber, SortOptions.Int);
```

The sorting works fine when i do and OrderBy on the Index:

```
session.Query<Fixture, Fixtures_All>.OrderBy(x => x.FixtureNumber).ToList()
```

But my problem is that when i do a dynamic Query on my Fixture document its like the query is still using my index:

```
session.Query<Fixture>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FixtureNumber == "WS1-1-1");
```

Returns no results, which i would expect it would as im not querying my index. But the following does work, which i find strange:

```
var fixNo = "WS1-15-1".Replace("-", "").Replace("WS", "");
session.Query<Fixture>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FixtureNumber == fixNo);
```

Why is my index affecting this dynamic index query ?

Also is there a better way to index my property without resorting to string replace to make it an integer ?

Thanks

**Note:**

If i just use the default string comparer on the SortOptions the results get sorted like so:

```
WS1-1-15-1
WS1-1-15-10
WS1-1-15-2
WS1-1-15-3
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Raven will always look for an index on the given type and for an indexed property (by name) on that type when doing an dynamic index. If it can't find one, it will auto-generate one first.

When you issue the following query:

```
session.Query<Fixture>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FixtureNumber == "WS1-1-1");
```

Raven will find that there is indeed an index on Fixture on the property FixtureNumber defined by the Fixtures_All index. The problem here is that the stored FixtureNumber inside the index is altered (stripped dash and letters) so Raven will use that to map your query (it doesn't know that it's been altered).

If you look at the index in the Raven studio you can select "Index Entries" to show what the actual index looks like on disk:
[image]

This is why you don't get any results when issue the query.

If you want to use an altered property in the index you can do the following:

```
Map = fixtures => from f in fixtures
    select new
    {
        ShortenFixtureNumber =  f.FixtureNumber.Replace("-", "").Replace("WS", ""),
        FixtureNumber = f.FixtureNumber
    };

Sort("ShortenFixtureNumber", SortOptions.Int);
```

Then you can create something I like to call a "Query Model" (not sure if that's the right name):

```
public class FixtureQueryModel
{
    public string FixtureNumber { get; set; }
    public int ShortenFixtureNumber { get; set; }
}
```

With this, I can query both by the index using the "Query model" and also query directly on the type:

```
var fixture = session.Query<FixtureQueryModel, Fixtures_All>()
                        .Where(x => x.FixtureNumber.StartsWith("WS1"))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.ShortenFixtureNumber)
                        .As<Fixture>()
                        .ToList();

var fixture2 = session.Query<Fixture>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FixtureNumber == "WS1-1-14-1");
```

However, this might seem rather complicated and in your case I think the default string sort comparer would work directly on an un-altered FixtureNumber, but hopefully this post provides some help into what's going on with indexes.

Comment: Ah Ok, is this documented some where? It was my impression from the documentation that an auto generated index would be created when querying without an index. I actually implemented your suggestion just after i posted as a work around because when i the indexed property using the default string sort comparer it sorts the strings in the wrong order.

Comment: I added some more info to the original question about what happens when i use the default sortoptions for the property in question.

Comment: This is a post from earlier this year where Ayende suggest basically what you've been doing, changing the output to the index: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/2V8Woydz8KQ - However if you need to query on that property as well, you might have to use two properties in the index, the original and the altered.